# How do you distinguish 'as much as X inches' and 'as many as Y inches'?

Tags: usage

***inches*** are a countable thing (so you would use ***as many as x inches*** in standard English), but many people say ***as much as x inches***.  How do you distinguish between the situations which use ***much*** and ***many***?

> Hurricane Gustav caused an estimated $372 million in crop damage,
> dumping ***as many as 20 inches*** of rain, agriculture officials
> said. - The New York Times
>
> Then, she rephotographs the results, enlarging the photographs to ***as
> much as 16 inches by 16 inches***. - The New York Times

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would consider "inches" as a measurement and use "as much as". But in certain contexts you may want to imagine each inch as a separate thing - for instance to emphasize the number that fall, or if each inch falls separately or has separate effects ("This is an inch of rain, this is another inch of rain...").

Similarly "X bottles" can refer either to a unit of measurement or to a glass container with fluid in it: "France produces as much as a billion bottles of wine per year" vs "I have as many as five bottles of wine for the party". This would also apply to something like barrels of wine/beer.